# SOLR sort is not working

Tags: sorting, solr

Adding sort criteria to SOLR query. First to sort by department_sortable and then by productname_sortable. Does get sorted by department_sortable but not by productname_sortable.

```
private List<SortField> getSortParameters() {
 List<SortField> sortFields = new ArrayList<SortField>();
 sortFields.add(generateSortField("department_sortable", SortDirection.ASC));
 sortFields.add(generateSortField("productname_sortable", SortDirection.ASC));
 return sortFields;
}


<field name="productname_sortable" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="department_sortable" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>


<copyField source="productname" dest="productname_sortable"/>
<copyField source="department" dest="department_sortable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is only one sort field is set to solrQuery. You can add multiple sort fields by using [SolrQuery#addSortFieldMethod](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.1.0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.java#SolrQuery.addSortField%28java.lang.String%2Corg.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.ORDER%29)

```
solrQuery.addSortField( "department_sortable", org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.ORDER.asc );
solrQuery.addSortField( "productname_sortable",org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.ORDER.asc );
```

or

```
solrQuery.addOrUpdateSort( "department_sortable", org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.ORDER.asc );
```

Related post [Sorting solr search results using multiple fields (solrj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059620/sorting-solr-search-results-using-multiple-fields-solrj)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
`solrQuery.setSort(new SortClause("department_sortable", "asc"));
solrQuery.setSort(new SortClause("productname_sortable", "asc"));`
```

or

```
`solrQuery.setSort(new SortClause("department_sortable", "asc"));
solrQuery.addSortField(new SortClause("productname_sortable", "asc"));`
```

or
  `solrQuery.setSort(new SortClause("department_sortable", "asc"));
    solrQuery.addSortField("productname_sortable", "asc");`